# Can I map more weapons from the wheel to keys?

Tags: pc, keyboard, assassins-creed-2

I know the AC series is ported from consoles, but on a PC I have a whole load of unused keys within easy reach.

Is there a way to map more weapons, currently accessed via the wheel only, to keys? For example, throwing knives would be very useful to quickly select, and the dagger, etc.

I find the wheel unwieldy (I frequently get the wrong weapon) and also it pauses the action. It would be nice to seamlessly throw a smoke bomb mid-fight, for example.

Comment: No, you only get the 4 slots.

Answer (score -1):

You get the preset four slots, and you can't change that unless you are a pro programmer.